# How to retrieve the fields of a namedtuple class (not instance)?

Tags: python-3.x, collections, namedtuple

Given a namedtuple:

```
from collections import namedtuple

MyNamedTuple = namedtuple('MyNamedTuple', ['foo','bar'])
```

I would like get an iterable over the fields of `MyNamedTuple` . Currently I do

```
[k for k in MyNamedTuple._fields]
```

but this uses the protected/private attribute `_fields`. Is there a way to do this without using  `_fields` or a protected/private attribute/methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say `_fields` is the right class attribute to use, as that is its [documented purpose](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._fields).

I don't know the reason they chose to prepend this attribute's name with an underscore, however.